# AWS Elemental MediaConvert .createJob() not working in JS SDK, but working in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

I'm trying to automatically create a compressed video and a thumbnail when one is uploaded to S3. The thumbnail is working how it should. For the compression, I'm trying to use AWS's `mediaconvert` to no avail. In my template, I've checked my Queue `arn` and role `arn` about 100 times. That exact template works when I create a job manually in AWS. But when I use

```
mediaConvert
.createJob(jobTemplate).promise()
.then(
   res => console.log('compress success', res),
   err => console.log('compress fail', err)
)
```

in my node API, it doesn't return anything. Not a `compress success` nor `compress fail`. One line above I've got `console.log('starting compression job')`, and that logs just fine. So I know it gets to the code.

Comment: See this JS example that is in the AWS JavaScript Github repo. It may help you with your use case. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/mediaconvert/src/emc_createjob.js

Comment: I've read and implemented that link and this [one](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascript/example_code/mediaconvert/emc_template_createjob.js) but both methods give no reponse. Not a complete or an error

Comment: If the code example is not working, then add a JS bug here in Github... https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/issues